# Help me make a cronjob/screen command please?

Tags: cron

Hi guys I want to set up a cronjob on reboot to do this

cd /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com && screen -d -m -S mcscreen && mono McMyAdmin.exe

The issue is when I execute this it seems to create the screen but doesn't do the mono McMyAdmin.exe in the screen...

Is there like a then command ?

so it does 1. then 2. then 3. ?

Could someone please help out :)

So I tried this:

so I did this:

```
@reboot screen -dmS minecraft
@reboot cd /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com
@reboot mono McMyAdmin.exe
```

It still doesn't work. The screen is created but it doesn't have the mono execution in it

I put this in it

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -dmS minecraft;
cd /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com;
mono McMyAdmin.exe;
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following into your crontab file

```
@reboot screen -d -m -S mcscreen 
@reboot mono /home/admin/vivalaminecraft.com/McMyAdmin.exe
```

Crontabs run through in order from top to bottom, so if things have the exact same time or parameter the top one will run first.

I don't know if `mcscreen` is a file inside vivilaminecraft.com but if it is then include the absolute path.

If that doesn't work you could try adding a shell script into /etc/init.d/ to run those commands, items in init.d get called during boot up.

Comment: That works if I do it manually but not as a cronjob =/

Still doesn't work. The screen gets created. If I do it manually it works perfectly...but for some reason this just doesn't want to work

Comment: I have edited my answer with something else to try.

Comment: So I tried to do that, but i'm a bit of a noob. I made a file just named it mserver and I put this code in it(look at main question, can't format here) That didn't work.

Comment: May have just noticed the problem, will test now...(it didn't have execute privileges)

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Alright I got it, I just learnt how to add it via chkconfig...thanks!